# How to access inner item from parent in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    signal searchTextEditedSignal(string text)
    SearchBox {
        id: search1
        textInput.onTextEditedSignal: searchTextEditedSignal(text)
    }
}
```

SearchBox.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10

FocusScope {
    id: focusScope
    width: 250; height: 28

    TextInput {
        id: textInput
        signal textEditedSignal(string msg)
        selectByMouse: true
        onTextEdited: {
            textEditedSignal(textInput.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I got error at runtime:

> qrc:/main.qml:15:9: Cannot assign to non-existent property "textInput"

I want to invoke the `searchTextEditedSignal` signal and use it in C++ code: connected to a C++ function. But the real invoker is the `TextInput` inside SearchBox.qml, so I need to delegate the `textEditedSignal` from SearchBox.qml to main.qml.

Comment: The id has a limited scope to the .qml file so you cannot and should not access an object using the id from another qml. In your particular case, define the textEditedSignal signal is focusScope: `FocusScope {
    id: focusScope
    width: 250; height: 28
    signal textEditedSignal(string msg)
    TextInput {
        id: textInput
        selectByMouse: true
        onTextEdited: {
            focusScope.textEditedSignal(textInput.text)
        }
    }
}`

Comment: And then you can use it in main.qml: `SearchBox {
        id: search1
        onTextEditedSignal: searchTextEditedSignal(text)
    }`

Comment: Another method (but bad design probably) could be to alias the child: `FocusScope { ... property alias textInput: textInput ... }`

Comment: @Amfasis Exactly, it is a bad design. It is best to only expose the signals and properties through the root.

Comment: I goes for eyllanesc's approach and it works! Only the object's signal should be exposed instead of the whole object, which ensures better encapsulation.